# Store session for cronjob

Tags: php, session, twitter, cron

I made a Twitter bot who replies on any user who used a specific keyword. Everytime I run it myself, it gets the since_id and max_id from Twitter API, makes an session_id from the since_id so I wont be tweeting the same message to the same user and tweet.

Now I'd like to let the script run by cronjob every 5 minutes. However, since I'm using $_SESSION it does not tweet the reply as I've got a if (!isset['$_SESSION='blabla''] check. When I remove the check, it works like a charm, but it might spam and might post the same reply to the same user with the same tweet.

So basically I was wondering if there's a workaround, so I can store $_SESSIONS with cronjobs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by storing sessions in a .txt and then reading it. Does this work for you?

BR